# How to convert time coordinate from "months since 2005-01-01 00:00:00" data type to normal time in Python?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, python-datetime, cartopy

I was working with the OHC NetCDF dataset. In the picture below, the time coordinate is in `"months since 2005-01-01 00:00:00"` unit and the data is like this `array([  0.5,   1.5,   2.5, ..., 207.5, 208.5, 209.5], dtype=float32)`. Here 0.5 may mean the data is `2005-01-15 00:00:00`.

[image: First image problem]

Now, I want the dataset like this image below. To summarize, I want my dataset in
`datetime64[ns]` instead of `float32` [image]

Comment: How did you try to solve this problem yourself? What were your attempts? What were the results and why were they not satisfying?

Comment: Do you know how to create a data series of the required dates? Have you tried to assign something new to time?

Comment: I think months are not very well recognized or standard time units. For instance netCDF4's num2date expects the calendar to be 360_day in order to use months as unit (`import netCDF4 as nc4;nc4.num2date(1.5,"months since 2005-01-01 00:00:00"` does not automatically work). I suggest converting these time values to another time unit on your own and replacing either in the netCDF itself or in the memory the time axis with new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use netCDF4 library to convert numbers to time.

Here is an example:

```
import xarray as xr
from netCDF4 import num2date
import numpy as np

# Dummy data
ds = xr.Dataset()
ds.coords["time"] = np.arange(10)
ds.time.attrs['units'] = "days since 2005-01-01 00:00:00"

# Now let's convert it to cftime.DatetimeGregorian format
times_new = num2date(times=ds.time, units=ds.time.units)

# Now you can add it to the dataset
ds.coords["rtime"] = times_new
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I got this error after implementing your method. `ValueError: 'months since' units only allowed for '360_day' calendar` @wind-circulation

Comment: But thank you. I get an idea from your answer, which was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by manually summing the value with starting date. Thanks, everyone for your idea and comment.

```
dates = []
for i in range(len(ohc.time.values)):
  date = (pd.to_datetime('2005-01-01') + pd.DateOffset(days=30*ohc['time'].values[i]))
  dates.append(date)
  
ohc.coords["rtime"] = dates
```